# Userform and Worksheet display works in Excel 2010 but not in Excel 2016

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I'm having an issue with a userform that updates the worksheet displayed behind it.  I'm able to reproduce the problem with the linked test worksheet.  In Excel 2010 the code works as expected.  In 2016 (and I assume 2013) the worksheet display only updates if the code is stopped in the debugger.  In addition, the userform will take 20-30 seconds to give control back to the user after the code completes and it will then take 5-10 seconds to even tab from field to field on the userform.

I would appreciate any guidance as to how to make this code work with the newer versions of Excel.

#### UserForm1

[image: UserForm1 Image]

#### UserForm1 Code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call DisplayBanner
    Debug.Print "End - Button 1"
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Call ExitForm
End Sub
```

#### Worksheet

[image: Worksheet Image]

#### Macro Code

```
Private xmlDoc As Object, Flow As Object

Sub OpenForm()  'RUN button on Home sheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    UserForm1.Show vbModal
End Sub

Sub DisplayBanner()
    'UserForm1.Hide

    Call DoBeforeStuff
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Cells(1, 6).Value = "Banner Text Here"
If UserForm1("CheckBox1").Value Then Stop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Call DoAfterStuff
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Cells(1, 6).Value = vbNullString
If UserForm1("CheckBox1").Value Then Stop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    If Not UserForm1.Visible Then UserForm1.Show
Debug.Print "End - DisplayBanner"
End Sub

Sub ExitForm()
    UserForm1.Hide
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Sub DoBeforeStuff()
    Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    xmlDoc.async = False: xmlDoc.validateOnParse = False
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    exFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename("Get XML File (*.*),*.*", , _
     "Select a XML file")
    If Not xmlDoc.Load(exFilename) Then
        Err.Raise xmlDoc.parseError.ErrorCode, , xmlDoc.parseError.reason
    End If
End Sub

Sub DoAfterStuff()
    Set Flow = xmlDoc.DocumentElement
    Set xParent = Flow.FirstChild
    p = 1
    For Each xParent In Flow.ChildNodes
        ParentNode = xParent.nodeName
        Sheets("OtherSheet").[Table1].Cells(p, 1).Value = ParentNode
        c = 1
        For Each xChild In xParent.ChildNodes
            nodeName = xChild.nodeName
            Sheets("OtherSheet").[Table1].Cells(p, c + 1).Value = nodeName
            c = c + 1
        Next xChild
        p = p + 1
Debug.Print ParentNode & " - " & p
    Next xParent
    Set xmlDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: When you are using the `stop` keyword, e.g. `If UserForm1("CheckBox1").Value Then Stop`, are you just expecting it to exit the sub routine? If so then use `exit sub` instead, `stop` is equivalent to setting a breakpoint, I know behaviour around breaking macro execution with Ctrl + Pause/Break has changed since 2010, It would be my best guess that is the culprit, although there is plenty more wrong with this code..

Comment: No, I'm not expecting to exit.  If I do stop, the screen updates as it should and I press run to continue.  The display does not update if the code runs unattended.

Comment: The only purpose of this code is to reproduce the issue.  What else is wrong with it?

Comment: `Screenupdating=False` on `openForm` before `doStuff`, the 0.01 second wait is weird. How does it perform with `msgbox("I broke"): exit sub` vs `stop`?